# How to show percentage alongside of values in plotly bar charts?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to plot percentage alongside values of each bar chart, something like that, or in one line with values (value + percentage)

[image]

I can achieve it with a pie chart with the help of this line:  `fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value+percent', textposition='outside')`. But struggling to do it with a bar chart. Can anyone help me to to it in `fig.update_traces` or by editing `fig.add_trace(go.Bar()`

[image]

Example of code I am using for plotting:

```
data = {'bin': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'type': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df1 = df[df['type']==0]
df2 = df[df['type']==1]


# dict for the dataframes and their names
dfs = {"df1" : df1, "df2" : df2}

# plot the data
temp=dict(layout=go.Layout(font=dict(family="Franklin Gothic", size=12), height=1000, width=1000))
fig = go.Figure()

for i in dfs:
        tmp = dfs[i]
        print(i, ': ', tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().keys()) 
        X = tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().keys()
        Y = tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().tolist()
        fig = fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = X,
                                   y = Y, 
                                   name = i))

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y}', textposition='outside')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi Azamat, please share your data, or a sample of it, for reproducibility. You could have a look at [mcve].

Comment: Pie charts can have percent information added to the annotations, but bar charts do not, so the easiest way to deal with this is to add a column of calculation results yourself. Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73149755/how-to-add-the-percentage-value-along-with-the-value-count-in-plotly-express-bar/73150165#73150165).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example keeping your code structure. It uses the argument `text` in `go.Bar(...)`. Here you can use HTML tags to properly format the text.

```
data = {'bin': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'type': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df1 = df[df['type']==0]
df2 = df[df['type']==1]


# dict for the dataframes and their names
dfs = {"df1" : df1, "df2" : df2}

# plot the data
temp=dict(layout=go.Layout(font=dict(family="Franklin Gothic", size=12), height=1000, width=1000))
fig = go.Figure()

for i in dfs:
        tmp = dfs[i]
        print(i, ': ', tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().keys()) 
        X = tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().keys()
        Y = tmp.groupby(['bin'])['id'].nunique().tolist()
        Y_text = [str(i) + f'<br>({i}%)</br>' for i in Y]
        
        fig = fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = X,
                                   y = Y,
                                   text = Y_text, 
                                   name = i))

fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
fig.show()
```